# Can't get my mac launchd script to run for mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, launchd

So I've installed mysql on my mac server and I'm trying to get it to run via launchd.

My command for starting up the server from cmd line is as follows:

```
mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --port=3306 --tmpdir=/tmp
```

This is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>600</integer>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/logs/mysqld.info.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/logs/mysqld.error.logg</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--user=_mysql</string>
            <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
            <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
            <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
            <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
            <string>--port=3306</string>
            <string>--tmpdir=/tmp</string>
        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is the error I'm getting from the system.log:

```
Oct  9 11:10:28 PMAs-Mac-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[1190]): Service could not initialize: 15A284: xpcproxy + 12644 [1472][19011403-4854-3CCD-9FCF-49C36302EB40]: 0xd
Oct  9 11:10:28 PMAs-Mac-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

From my understandings, this is a permissions error. I've made sure that `/usr/local/mysql` is owned my `_mysql`, so I'm not sure what the problem is there.

I've also double checked the permission of the plist file:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1607 Oct  9 11:42 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Comment: It sometimes happens to me as well on Mac OS X Lion. If you run "ps ax | grep mysql" is there any mysqld process? If so, kill it "kill -s sigkill <Process_PID>". It works for me.

Comment: @viktor77 - There is no process running at all, it's not starting. When I run the command from the command line, it starts okay. It won't start from launchd however.